# Creating third order butterworth filter with Sallen–Key topology

Tags: filter, ltspice, sallen-key

I am trying to design a third order Butterworth filter with Sallen–Key topology. I am quite new to this and there is not much only about third order variations.I have the following requirements:

- Gain: 1 (unity)
- Passband (cut off): 116 Hz
- Stopband: 500 Hz
- Stop band attenuation: ≥ 35 dB

I thought I could make the original sallen key configuration into a third order by simply adding an RC circuit at the output, then calculating both of the fc to be 116 Hz. The 2nd order circuit was calculated by normalizing the resistor and capacitor values by setting fc to 1 rad/s, then scaling up (method shown in image). These values where multiplied by m = 116 (resistor) and 1/116 (capacitor), yielding:

- R1 & R2: 116 ohm
- C1:16.7 μF
- C2:8.36 μF

With this the passband is correct (116 Hz at -3 dB), however obviously the attenuation is not steep enough to yield the passband attenuation. I am not sure on how to configure the third order section and was wondering if I could get some assistance on this. This is a revision piece, where we were told to make a third order butterworth filter with sallen key topology.

[image: filter schematic][image: sallen key 2nd order calculation]

Comment: Won't the RC on right cause the gain to be less than 1 at the design corner no matter what you do? Is there is a reason a 2nd opamp isn't being used? And have you performed the calculation at your stop band using the Butterworth polynomial?

Comment: I would suggest using [standard values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) for your components. It's one thing to make a perfect model in LTSpice, but the moment you want to build it in the real world, you will be disapointed that you cant get a 227 ohm resistor. (You can get close with 1% resistors). Small changes in values can cause big changes in results in some cases.

Comment: i have tried adding another op amp, feeding the rc circuit output to the non inverting input, with the inverting input looped to ground however it makes no difference

Comment: @periblepsis i wasnt really sure on how to do that, i thought that having the third order there would increase the attenuation by 20db per decade? i am quite new to this topic sorry

Comment: I think your issue here is that you're misunderstanding the filter order of Butterworth filters.  Proper Butterworth filters are supposed to form poles equidistant along the unit circle.  The 2nd order filter you calculated has this property.  But if you simply tack on a first order RC (always located at s=-1 + 0j), then the resultant filter as a whole does not have its poles equidistant anymore.  The 2nd order section must be calculated such that when you add the RC section, the entire filter as a whole has all three poles properly spaced.

Comment: @confusionpersonified For example, a 2nd order Butterworth has \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{2}\$. But a 3rd order Butterworth has its 2nd order section with \$\zeta=\frac12\$. Do you know that fact? Or why?

Comment: @SteKulov I see, thank you, yes I understand when making 2nd order filters, as there is a lot online to help, and lecture notes, however we were not given any help on making orders above this in reference to poles, so I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: @periblepsis yes the combined response of the first and second-order section would achieve the flatness characteristic of a Butterworth filter

Comment: @confusionpersonified  Check out Figure 5-26 of [this free online book](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/op-amp-applications-handbook.html).  It's a table of Butterworth pole locations and properties.  You can find the Q for each imaginary pole pair, and then use something [like this calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm) (scroll down to 2nd part) to enter in that Q value.  Basically you split a design into independent 2nd order sections (and an additional 1st order if it's odd numbered).

Comment: @SteKulov thank you! I will take a look

Comment: @periblepsis id assume that the multiplication is commutative, so the order the first-order and second-order sections are cascaded wouldnt change the theoretical frequency response of the filter? thank you for your help so far though

Comment: @confusionpersonified When ordering cascaded stages, the usual goals are low noise and overload/saturation avoidance. Some useful hand-waving rules, when lacking time or interest for quantitative calcs, are to put higher Q sections in the middle of the chain, to keep the 1st sections as either low-pass or band-pass so that incoming HF noise is suppressed right away, that the tail-end stages should be high-pass or band-pass to help avoid output dc offset, and that if there are any all-pass sections those probably should be closer to the input than the output.

Comment: @periblepsis would this not impact the unity gain?

Comment: @periblepsis stupid question sorry, may i ask if adding a second op amp is absolutely necessary in order for it to be considered a butterworth filter, and not just a third order sallen key filter?

Comment: @confusionpersonified A simple RC would have the same shape as an opamp buffered one. And it is the right shape for the 1st order stage (which because its Q is lower should go first in the chain) of the Butterworth. So you have a good answer below without the need for a 2nd opamp. If that qualifies for you, I'd go with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150420/discussion-between-confusionpersonified-and-periblepsis).

Comment: @confus The relative ratios of C1, C2, and C3 (shown in the answer below) are determined by solving for three equations based upon the real root, and the real part and the imaginary part of one of the complex roots. That's three equations and three unknowns: C1=3.54681827688408, C2=1.39264678170264, C3=0.202451072765786.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the standard tables, the circuit configuration you require with the resistor and capacitor values normalised to 1 rad/sec is as below....

[image: Filter design]

First we must frequency scale the capacitors.

C1 = 3.546 F/(2 * pi * 116) = 4.87 mF

C2 = 1.392 F/(2 * pi * 116) = 1.91 mF

C3 = 0.202 F/(2 * pi * 116) = 0.277 mF

Next we must impedence scale all the component values to get realistic values.

Choose a standard value for C1 and calculate the impedence scaling factor

let C1 = 100 nF

Impedence scaling factor = 4.87 mF/100 nF = 48.7k

C2 = 1.91 mF/48.7k = 39.2 nF

C3 = 0.277 mF/48.7k = 5.69 nF

R1 = R2 = R3 = 1R * 48.7k = 48.7k

Final circuit...

[image: Final Filter]

As you can see the output is 0.707 down (-3 dB) at 116 Hz.

Although the component values are not standard values, their values are in the right ball park to be practical.