# Using Operation-Amplifier circuit to apply differential equation

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

$$ 6b(t)+\frac{8d}{dt}b(t)+\frac{10d^2}{dt^2}b(t)+\frac{4d^3}{dt^3}b(t)=12a(t) $$

I would like to implement this linear equation by using any type of op-amps. The solution will be the function b(t), so we can set the initial conditions to be zero. a(t) is the input.
It was hard to grasp this differential equation so it was a challenge for me to apply this circuit. I will be glad for your help. You are free to use inductors and/or capacitors if you want. Thank you.

This is the circuit that I have tried to build but it only gives 0.
[image]

Comment: Looks like homework. Smells like homework. We don't do your homework for you. Show us what work you've done yourself and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: At least it doesn't taste like homework :D. It's not homework but I refrained from sharing the circuit that I've tried because it was wrong. Now I shared. Have a look at it.

Comment: I've voted to reopen - but could you also describe how you got to that circuit from your equation?

Comment: Actually, I can't. Trying to convert similar circuits from youtube to the equation given above. That's why I didn't want to share the circuit. I don't know who closed the question but q&a websites can be cruel sometimes. This is my second question. Please forgive if I made any mistake in the procedure.

Comment: @Esmeralda We get a *lot* of people posting questions that amount to "I don't want to do my homework, someone do it for me", and answering those isn't productive for anyone, so we have a policy of closing and not answering questions that look like homework problems where the one asking hasn't made any attempt to solve it themself. On the other hand, if someone asks "I have this homework problem, here's what I tried, but the professor says it's wrong, what did I do wrong?", that's a productive question that helps people learn, hence the requirement of showing your attempt.

Comment: I would rewrite this differential equation in Laplace domain, much easier to deal with when it comes to assembling filters.

Comment: We haven't covered it in our lectures yet, but I would still be ok if it solves the circuit.

Comment: Inductors are not normally used in opamp feedback circuits... I would have expected three feedback capacitors; d/dt of d/dt of d/dt. Maybe try breaking down the requirement equation into simpler steps, like try implementing just one or two of the terms, to validate the approach.

Comment: @Esmeralda What have you covered? This is a 3rd order low-pass filter that can be implemented with 3 capacitors and just one opamp. In fact, we discussed the exact topology you might consider using in the [selected answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/694851). You could either hold the capacitors at specific values and solve for the resistor ratios or visa versa. But a lot may depend on the tools you can apply.

Comment: I suggest to use analog computing building blocks. Op-amps are implementation details and somewhat obscure the big picture. Analog computing has its own symbolic language and everyone who did it knew it back then. There are excellent free book/article collections on Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/analogmatrixmethodsnavarroanalogcomputerfundamentalswithanintroductiontomatrixprogrammingmethods1962/ and https://archive.org/details/analog-computer-textbooks/ These materials will teach you the approaches. Op-amp translation can be the last step :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### discussion

I believe you mentioned that you haven't covered Laplace in lectures, yet. This, plus your starting approach, makes me think you are working on things more like analog computers (old days.)

For notation convenience set \$D=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\$, so that \$D\$ is just an operator and then your equation becomes:

$$\begin{align*}
\left[4D^3+10D^2+8D+6\right]v_{out}&=12v_{in}\tag{1}
\\\\
\left[D^3+\frac52D^2+2D+\frac32\right]v_{out}&=3v_{in}\tag{2}\label{td}
\\\\
\therefore \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}&=\frac3{D^3+\frac52D^2+2D+\frac32}\tag{3}\label{lap}
\end{align*}$$

I'll get to Eq. \$\ref{lap}\$, later.

### analog computers

For now, re-arrange Eq. \$\ref{td}\$ to get:

$$\dddot{v_{out}}=3\left[v_{in}-\frac12v_{out}\right]-\frac52\ddot{v_{out}}-2\dot{v_{out}}\tag{4}\label{ac}$$

That's great because a standard RC integrator has \$v_o=-\frac1{R\,C}\int v_{i}\$, which means such a stage can be used to develop each of the required terms found in Eq. \$\ref{ac}\$.

Start by assuming \$\dddot{v_{out}}\$ exists. That can be integrated to \$-\ddot{v_{out}}\$, then to \$\dot{v_{out}}\$, and finally to \$-v_{out}\$. Since \$v_{out}\$ is desired, flip the sign and assume to start with \$-\dddot{v_{out}}\$, instead. Apply:

[image]

Then to that, apply:

[image]

And now to get the final result apply:

[image]

You now have the important terms for:

$$\dddot{v_{out}}=-3\left[\vphantom{\frac52}v_{out}-\frac12v_{in}\right]-\left(+\frac52\ddot{v_{out}}\right)+\left(\vphantom{\frac52}-2\dot{v_{out}}\right)\tag{5}\label{acx}$$

All that can be handled now with a few more opamps to complete the picture (if I didn't miss anything -- look closely over this as I may have made a mistake in translating the image below -- but at least it points out the general approach even if I get a sign wrong below):

[image]

It's possible this is the approach required of you. But I'll move on from here.

### transfer function

It's just a notation change to turn the transfer function shown by Eq. \$\ref{lap}\$ into Laplace form:

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=2\cdot\frac{\frac32}{s^3+\frac52s^2+2s+\frac32}\tag{6}$$

This is recognizable as a low-pass, 3rd order filter with a DC gain of 2. There are several alternatives to turn this into a filter design. One such filter that could be applied is shown at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/694851).

However, this is about having a straight-forward process so I'll take a simpler-to-apply approach that uses two opamps. That will help isolate the issues.

### design

Given it is 3rd order, there will be a real root and a conjugate pair. The real root will be used for one opamp for a 1st order response and the conjugate pair will be used in my example for another opamp with a 2nd order response. The schematic will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb4zGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll be using SymPy/Python/Sagemath as my tools. But if you wish, you can refresh your memory on [cubics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) and solve it exactly. Regardless, step 1 is to get the roots:

```
for i in roots(s**3 + 5/2*s**2 + 2*s + 3/2,s):i.n()
-1.85809432949655
-0.320952835251724 - 0.839206763026694*I
-0.320952835251724 + 0.839206763026694*I
expand((s-(-0.320952835251724-0.839206763026694*I))*(s-(-0.320952835251724+0.839206763026694*I)))
s**2 + 0.641905670503448*s + 0.807278713565862
```

I'll center around \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors for \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_3\$.

Normally, it would be better to consider the capacitor values first and then pick odd-valued resistors, since they come in wider varieties. But this is schoolwork. So I'll set the resistors instead and let the capacitor values fall where they may. Feel free (as an education) to set the capacitor values to readily available values and work out the resistors. I'll leave that to you.

The transfer function, with gain of 2, for the 1st order stage is \$2\cdot\frac{\omega_{_0}}{s+\omega_{_0}}\$. Given the real root above, \$\omega_{_0}=1.85809432949655\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$. So the capacitor for the 1st order stage (also the first stage) is:

$$C_1=\frac{1}{\omega_{_0}\cdot R_1}=\frac{1}{1.85809432949655\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\,\cdot\,10\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 53.8186\:\mu\text{F}$$.

The transfer function, with gain of 1, for the 2nd order stage is \$\frac{\omega_{_0}^{\,2}}{s^2+\frac{\omega_{_0}}{Q}\,s+\omega_{_0}^{\,2}}\$. Given the 2nd order denominator made from the roots above, \$\frac{\omega_{_0}}{Q}=0.641905670503448\$ and \$\omega_{_0}^{\,2}=0.807278713565862\:\frac{\text{rad}^2}{\text{s}^2}\$. The feedback capacitor for the 2nd order stage is:

$$C_2=\frac{1}{\frac{\omega_{_0}}{Q}\,\cdot\,\left(R_2\mid\mid R_3\right)}=\frac{1}{0.641905670503448\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\,\cdot\,\left(10\:\text{k}\Omega\mid\mid 10\:\text{k}\Omega\right)}\approx 311.5723\:\mu\text{F}$$.

The final capacitor (grounded) for the 2nd order stage then falls out as:

$$\begin{align*}C_3=\frac{1}{\omega_{_0}^{\,2}\,\cdot\,R_2\,\cdot\,R_3\,\cdot\,C_2}&=\frac{1}{0.807278713565862\:\frac{\text{rad}^2}{\text{s}^2}\,\cdot\,10\:\text{k}\Omega\,\cdot\,10\:\text{k}\Omega\,\cdot\,C_2}\\\\&\approx 39.7574\:\mu\text{F}\end{align*}$$

And that's it.

### validation

I'll provide a schematic using LTspice that includes both the transfer function itself (no components or parts) and then the final schematic:

[image]

This shows the ideal response (red) and the actual response using models for actual parts (green, and in this case a decompensated LT1127 opamp.) It's clear that the transfer functions match well up to a point.

The process above works reasonably well and uses fewer opamps and parts.

### time domain

If we set:

$$\begin{align*}
\alpha_{_0}&=-1.85809432949655\\
\beta_{_0}&=0.839206763026694\\
\alpha_{_1}&=-0.320952835251724
\end{align*}$$

then,

$$\begin{align*}
\left[D^3+\frac52D^2+2D+\frac32\right]v_{out}&=3v_{in}
\\\\
\left[D-\alpha_{_1}\vphantom{\left(\right)^{\,2}}\right]\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_0}\right)^2+ \beta_{_0}^{\,2}\right]v_{out}&=3v_{in}
\end{align*}$$

Just to verify:

```
collect(expand((s-(-1.85809432949655))*((s-(-0.320952835251724))**2+0.839206763026694**2)),s)
s**3 + 2.5*s**2 + 2.0*s + 1.5
```

That pans out. The only remaining problem is that this isn't homogeneous and we don't know what \$v_{in}\$ is.

If we happen to suggest, for example, that \$v_{in}=A\,\sin\left(\omega_{_0}\,t\right)\$ then the right side can be annihilated as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\left[D-\alpha_{_1}\vphantom{\left(\right)^{\,2}}\right]\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_0}\right)^2+ \beta_{_0}^{\,2}\right]v_{out}&=3v_{in}
\\\\
\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_2}\right)^2+ \omega_{_0}^{\,2}\right]\left[D-\alpha_{_1}\vphantom{\left(\right)^{\,2}}\right]\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_0}\right)^2+ \beta_{_0}^{\,2}\right]v_{out}&=\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_2}\right)^2+ \omega_{_0}^{\,2}\right]3v_{in}
\\\\
\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_2}\right)^2+ \omega_{_0}^{\,2}\right]\left[D-\alpha_{_1}\vphantom{\left(\right)^{\,2}}\right]\left[\left(D-\alpha_{_0}\right)^2+ \beta_{_0}^{\,2}\right]v_{out}&=0, \text{where }\alpha_{_2}=0
\end{align*}$$

and now it is homogeneous. It's also in a form we can use, as:

- \$\left[D-\alpha\right]^m\$ annihilates any solution of the general form:

  \$\quad\quad f\left(t\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} A_k\,t^k\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\$.
- \$\left[\left(D-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\right]^m\$ annihilates any solution of the general form:

  \$\quad\quad f\left(t\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} A_{2k}\,t^k\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\cos\left(\beta\,t\right) + A_{2k+1}\,t^k\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)\$

So, the general form of the solution with unspecified constants is:

$$v_{out}=A_{_0}\cos\left(\omega_{_0}\,t\right) + A_{_1}\sin\left(\omega_{_0}\,t\right)+A_{_2}\,\exp\left(\alpha_{_1}\,t\right)+\exp\left(\alpha_{_0}\,t\right)\left[A_{_3}\cos\left(\beta_{_0}\,t\right) + A_{_4}\sin\left(\beta_{_0}\,t\right)\right]$$

Some terms are just part of the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation and some are remaining terms expressing the particular solution to the nonhomogeneous equation with undetermined coefficients. But at least you are now in a position of working through a process to determine the coefficients.

For example, to start you might note that at \$t=0\$ you know that \$A_{_0}+A_{_2}+A_{_3}=0\$. From the derivative, at \$t=0\$, you also know that \$A=A_{_1}\cdot\omega_{_0}+A_{_2}\cdot\alpha_{_1}+A_{_3}\cdot\alpha_{_0}+A_{_4}\cdot\beta_{_0}\$. And so on.

Just something to consider if you were looking to create a time domain solution.

Comment: I'm quite impressed with your MSPaint skillz.

Comment: @SteKulov Yeah. That's what makes me special. ;)